# Dealing with missing n-grams in Naive Bayes classifier

Tags: nlp, naive-bayes-classifier, ngrams

I am doing sentiment analysis on code-mixed text data, i.e English used interchangeably with another language. The dataset I currently have is very small in size, approx 3.5k samples.

I am sure that this dataset will not contain all possible n-grams that are used in the language. Are there any ways I can deal with this problem without increasing the number of samples in the dataset?

For now, I am using a MNB classifier to do the sentiment analysis.